# gatsby failed due to missing regenerator-runtime/runtime module

Tags: macos, gatsby

I am trying out gatsby

Here is how I install `gatsby-cli`:

```
$ npm install --global gatsby-cli
/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.6/bin/gatsby -> /Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.6/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js
gatsby-cli@1.1.20 /Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.6/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli
├── convert-hrtime@2.0.0
├── hosted-git-info@2.5.0
├── stack-trace@0.0.10
├── resolve-cwd@2.0.0 (resolve-from@3.0.0)
├── source-map@0.5.7
├── bluebird@3.5.1
├── babel-code-frame@6.26.0 (js-tokens@3.0.2, esutils@2.0.2, chalk@1.1.3)
├── execa@0.8.0 (p-finally@1.0.0, strip-eof@1.0.0, is-stream@1.1.0, get-stream@3.0.0, signal-exit@3.0.2, npm-run-path@2.0.2, cross-spawn@5.1.0)
├── fs-extra@4.0.2 (universalify@0.1.1, jsonfile@4.0.0, graceful-fs@4.1.11)
├── common-tags@1.4.0
├── yargs@8.0.2 (decamelize@1.2.0, get-caller-file@1.0.2, camelcase@4.1.0, y18n@3.2.1, which-module@2.0.0, set-blocking@2.0.0, yargs-parser@7.0.0, require-main-filename@1.0.1, require-directory@2.1.1, string-width@2.1.1, cliui@3.2.0, os-locale@2.1.0, read-pkg-up@2.0.0)
├── yurnalist@0.2.1 (strip-bom@3.0.0, detect-indent@5.0.0, leven@2.1.0, semver@5.4.1, object-path@0.11.4, death@1.1.0, is-builtin-module@1.0.0, is-ci@1.0.10, chalk@1.1.3, debug@2.6.9, node-emoji@1.8.1, read@1.0.7, loud-rejection@1.6.0, invariant@2.2.2, rimraf@2.6.2, inquirer@3.3.0)
├── pretty-error@2.1.1 (utila@0.4.0, renderkid@2.0.1)
├── babel-runtime@6.26.0 (regenerator-runtime@0.11.0)
├── lodash@4.17.4
└── core-js@2.5.1
```

Then when I tried to print out the version to see if the installation is successful, I got this:

```
$ gatsby --version
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/antkong/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.6/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js:88:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

My version of npm and node

```
$ node --version
v4.8.6
$ npm --version
2.15.11
```

OS platform is macOS High Sierra

What did I miss during the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not supporting Node 4 anymore — try upgrading to Node 8 & NPM 5 and it should be smooth sailing!